# How to create a new Automation Acount in Azure China

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-china

MSDN says going to Azure portal -> New -> Type "Automation" in the search bar and select "Automation" in the drop down list. I successfully created an automation account in my American Azure using this method.

However, when it comes to Azure China, after I typed "Automation" in the search bar, nothing showed up.
[image]

It simply told me no results found. I am very confused here, what should I do to create an automation account in Azure China? (I am positive automation is supported in Azure China, I read the official document)

Comment: Could you show some screenshot about your question?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Please see the attached snapshot. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you try `Automation Accounts` or Click `More services`, sort by name find `Automation Accounts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try search `Automation Accounts` or Click More services, sort by name find Automation Accounts.

If it does not work, please ensure you had Registered `Microsoft.Automation` providers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I believe that's the root cause. I just checked it and turns out the subscription didn't register Microsoft.Automation providers. I am registering it right now, is it normal that it is still 'Registering' after 20 mins?

Comment: @NJUHOBBY Yes, it needs some time.

Comment: can you please tell me normally how long will it take? Thanks.

Comment: @NJUHOBBY Sorry, I am not sure. Maybe you could use PowerShell to register it. `Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Automation`.  Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services).